# ZVS Circuit as LC Oscillator

Tags: zvs

I was wondering if a ZVS circuit would be suitable as an LC oscillator. I have used a ZVS circuit before for induction heating, and observed that the idle power draw was relatively high. I used a circuit like this:

[image]

To reduce the idle power draw, I was wondering if I could replace L2 with a resistor or add a resistor between 15V and L2.

Another idea that came to mind was just to reduce the value of C1 and increase the value of L1 in order to increase impedance. However, I would like the circuit to be compatible with a variety of inductances and capacitances.

Would either of these ideas work?

I have looked at the Hartley oscillator, but I don't think it is suitable for the various inductances and capacitances I want to test with.

Comment: All your proposals are too passive (no pun intended) to increase efficiency. What you need is an active circuit - a dedicated oscillator IC with proper gate drivers or a ZVS controller. The reason your circuit performs poorly, is that the circuit depends to some degree on the switching thresholds of the transistors. You need active electronics to remove that dependency. Best you can do is match the transistors and use ones that have an ideal (sharp) switching threshold to minimize operating in the linear (ohmic) regime.

Comment: @MOSFET That isn't really true -- the circuit can be very efficient, and is a common choice in lighting circuits for example.

Comment: @TimWilliams It can be very efficient over a very narrow band of operating points. To maintain high-efficiency with varying L's & C's while also minimizing current draw at idle, an active approach should be taken. I agree with the high-efficiency lighting example, but that is fixed load at one operating point and the idle current draw doesn't matter in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit can be viewed as a self-oscillating mixer.

The average voltage during each half-cycle is fixed at `+15V`.  This determines voltage amplitude.

We imply a loss resistor somewhere; in parallel with L1 and C1 is the simplest case.  The load current dissipated in this resistor, is similarly mixed synchronously with the oscillator voltage, and returned to the supply.  Thus AC load current is reflected as DC supply current, and we have conservation of power as expected.

Given these hints, and the equivalent diagrams when one or the other transistor is switched on, the exact amplitude and power dissipation can be calculated; this is left as an exercise for the student.

To "reduce idle power draw", choose higher impedance components, and higher Q factor, so that the equivalent parallel loss resistance becomes larger.  Note that \$Z_0 = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$, so to maintain constant frequency while increasing \$Z_0\$, L should be increased and C reduced, proportionally.  Typically, a high-Q (polypropylene, C0G ceramic, etc.) capacitor is used, so that the inductor Q dominates.  Whatever the total Q factor (note that capacitor and inductor Qs act "in parallel", i.e. \$Q_\text{tot} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{Q_L}+\frac{1}{Q_C}})\$, the equivalent parallel resistance is \$EPR = Q Z_0\$.  Thus, raising \$Z_0\$ and Q is necessary to satisfy this goal.

It's not clear what "variety of inductances and capacitances" you wish to choose, while still being compatible with a "reduce[d] idle power draw", but in short, you will have to find some compromise between acceptable power dissipation, and range of supported components.

There is also power consumption due to gate bias, for which, more is required at higher frequencies (even if an emitter follower circuit is used to dynamically boost it).  This further limits component selection.

Also, the supply inductor value must be much larger than L, further constraining values.

(Finally, L needs to be tapped, but this can be solved by using a very high inductance tapped inductor, and putting the inductance proper in parallel with it.  Core loss factors into total losses, of course.)

The supply voltage can also be reduced.  Note that gate bias voltage must be at least somewhat above V<sub>GS(th)</sub>, but `+15V` (note I use `tttext` to indicate net name; it is merely labeled as such, and need not be the actual voltage suggested by that name) can be adjusted somewhat freely, given that, at low voltages, some power will be drawn from the gate bias circuit itself, limiting minimum operation.

For yet lower power, consider lower 'on' voltage devices, such as logic-level MOSFETs, or BJTs.

Comment: I will use a 5V power supply. For the transistors, would the [DMG2302UK](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG2302UK.pdf) be a good option? The current vs gate source voltage is on the top right of page 3.

Comment: Again, impossible to tell without component values. I see your comment on the other answer; such large capacitors are most likely not high-Q types, and the worst-case combination, 1uH with 100uF, implies an impedance far too low for this transistor. Again, you will have to determine for yourself, what combination of {L, C, Q} is acceptable for operation, and at what power level.

Answer (score 0):

We need further information to help you.  Do you want (a) to reduce the power draw of this particular circuit, or (b) just an oscillator?

If (a), there are some ways of reducing power losses, but the question is: is power loss really a big problem?  Are any of the devices (perhaps the MOSFETs) getting too hot, perhaps they are getting damaged?  Is the circuit drawing too much power from the power supply?

Just one example of reducing power loss: the waveform at the gate of the MOSFET should have fast edges, so that the MOSFET switches rapidly.  You mey be better off using BJTs rather than MOSFETs, since they have a lower turn-on voltage than MOSFETs, but beware of issues that may limit the speed of BJTs, such as storage time.  Another method is to put a second winding on L1 that has more turns, so its voltage is higher than what is on the L1 primary, and use this new "floating" winding to drive a suitable gate driver.  These are just two methods that may be useful to create better drive waveforms for the switching device (whether MOSFET, or BJT).

If (b), then many other types of oscillators may be more suitable for your application.  So what is your application?  What is the power supply voltage, what is the "load" that will be driven by this oscillator, and what is the frequency & voltage that this has to generate?  Does the output voltage have to be a sine wave, or can it be a square wave, or triangle wave?

> I have looked at the Hartley oscillator, but I don't think it is suitable for the various inductances and capacitances I want to test with.

What are these "various inductors and capacitors" that you want to use?  We will need this information to help you.

Comment: My application is to look at the waveform of the lc circuit to determine the resonant frequency. I was thinking in the range of 1-100uF for capacitance and 1-100uF for inductance.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest just use a signal generator and a scope.  Connect the L and C in parallel, add a resistor in series with the output of the sig gen about 1k, then connect the resistor to the parallel LC.   Connect scope ch1 to sig-gen, ch2 to LC node and sig-gen output.  Sweep the frequency of the sig-gen, and plot the voltage ch1 & ch2 vs frequency.  That will tell you much about resonant tanks.

Comment: The thing is, I am trying to do have this experiment on a circuit board with only a laptop as input output. For a scope I was thinking an ADC with a high sampling rate would do, but I'm not sure about signal generation. Would a square wave from a 555 work?

Comment: The square way will be OK, but will give very different results compared to pure sinewave - you may need to experiment a bit.  You can generate triangle waves from square waves, and then very close to sinusoidal waveforms from the triangle waves, plenty of links on the internet that can show you how.    Suggest trying this out on the test bench with a scope before committing this to a PCB with ADC.